# Show that $(\text{Map}(Q,R),+,\cdot)$ is a ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Be $R$ a ring, $Q$ any non-empty set and  $S=\text{Map}\left(Q,R\right)$  the set of all mappings from $Q$ to $R$, therefore there is for addition and multiplication the following functions:
> $$(f+g)(m):= f(m) + g(m)$$
> $$(fg)(m):= f(m)g(m)$$
>
> 1. Show that $S$ is a ring,
> 2. If $R$ is a field, is $S$ then a field as well?

How do I show for a set of functions that it is a ring? What can we assume about this set?

Comment: By $M$ do you mean $Q$?

Comment: @NoahSolomon Yes. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's show that $(S,+)$ is an abelian group:**
$+$ is associative since $$(f+(g+h))(m)=f(m)+(g+h)(m)=f(m)+(g(m)+h(m))=(f(m)+g(m))+h(m)=((f+g)+h)(m)$$
which is valid for $R$ is a ring.

For a similar reason, $+$ is commutative (just like before, it inherits that property from $R$).

The function $e(m)=0_R$ is clearly one such that $(e+f)(m)=(f+e)(m)=f(m)+e(m)=f(m)$ and there is an neutral element.

And $(-f)(m)=-f(m)$ is an inverse of $f(m)$ where $-f(m)$ exists for $R$ is a ring. So every element has an inverse.

**Let's show that $(S,\cdot)$ is a monoid:**
$e(m)=1_R$ is  clearly a neutral element of $(S,\cdot)$ for $(fe)(m)=(ef)(m)=f(m)e(m)=f(m)$.

And just like before, it's associative for it inherits the property from the multiplication on $R$ (proof is similar to the one mentioned in the beginning).

**Let's show that $\cdot$ distributes over $+$:**
$(f\cdot(g+h))(m)=f(m)\cdot (g+h)(m)=f(m)\cdot (g(m)+h(m))$ $=f(m)\cdot g(m)+f(m)\cdot h(m)=(f\cdot g)(m)+(f\cdot h)(m)=(f\cdot g+f\cdot h)(m)$ which works because $f(m),g(m),h(m)\in R$ and $\cdot$ distributes over $+$ on $R$.

*Since $(S,+)$ is an abelian group, $(S,\cdot)$ is a monoid and $\cdot$ distributes over $+$, we have that $(S,+,\cdot)$ is a ring.*

The second problem is similar. By the way $f+g$ and $fg$ where defined, $S$ inherits some of the properties of the field $R$. Are those properties such that $S$ is a field?

Comment: Yes, since it inherits associtivity, commutativity and distributivity from R, and clearly there are neutral elements for addition and mulitplication. The multiplicative, additive inverse is similar to your proof.

Comment: Am I on the right direction?

Comment: Well, actually no, it isn't lol. Let $f\neq 0$ and $f(n)=0$ then let $g\neq 0$ such that $g(n)\neq 0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\neq n$. Then we have $fg=gf=0$ ([omit this parenthesis if not familiar with the notion of a domain] this means that $\text{map}(Q,R)$ has zero divisors and is thus not a domain and thus not a field $\square$.) then, if $g$ has a multiplicative inverse $g^{-1}$, then $fgg^{-1}=0g^{-1}$ an thus $f=0$, a contradiction, so $g\neq 0$ doesn´t have an inverse and $\text{Map(Q,R)}$ isn't a field $\square$.

Comment: Also, I edited my answer. I had forgotten to add the fact that $\cdot$ must distribute over $+$.

Comment: Thank you very much.